# How to set form "action" in comment form

Tags: php, html

This is very silly question but as a learner I need your help seriously...
I am creating a comment box for my website, I don't know how to set form action in html. Is any PHP required to display a user comment on that Web page. I have not create any php yet.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="form_row">
                <label>Name</label><br />
                <input name="fullname" type="text" maxlength="30"   id="fullname" />
            </div>
            <div class="form_row">
                <label>Email (*required)</label>
              <br />
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" maxlength="30" />
            </div>
            <div class="form_row">
                <label>Comment</label><br />
                <textarea  name="comment" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"  class="submit_btn" />
        </form>
```

Comment: change the `action` attribute and set the path to the PHP script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am creating a comment box for my website, I don't know how to set form action in html

The value of the attribute should be a URL, much as for `<a href`.

> Is any PHP required to display a user comment on that Web page.

In order to:

- Read the form data
- Store it in a database on the server
- Read it from the database and insert it into pages requested from the server by other browsers

… you need to use server side programming. PHP is a programming language you can use for server side programming. There are many others.

Comment: Can you please provide a PHP scripts for that form.

Comment: No. Writing a comment system from scratch is far too broad a subject for a Stackoverflow question.